# Google scripts - Gosu - variable syntax

Tags: gosu

Whats the syntax required in order to insert a variable to a json string in Gosu script. I have this var:

```
var mydate = '"' + todayString + '"';
```

Currently I am truing to insert this var inside a JSON string as the following but I get an error:

```
{
"brandId": "10820",
"dateRange": "CUSTOM",
"startDate": "2016-08-15",
**"endDate": "+mydate+"**
}
```

I know that in Javascript it should be like that:
"endDate": '${mydate}'

Whats the required syntax for Gosu? thank you.

Comment: In JavaScript you would just drop the quotes and the `+`s since `endDate: myDate` is already sufficient if `myDate` is an `Object`, such as a formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

A String literal example:

```
uses java.time.LocalDate
uses gw.lang.reflect.json.Json

var mydate = LocalDate.now();
var json = '{ \
  "brandId": "10820", \
  "dateRange": "CUSTOM", \
  "startDate": "2016-08-15", \
  "endDate": "${mydate}" \
}'

var bindings: Dynamic = Json.fromJson(json)
print(bindings.endDate)
```

Read https://gosu-lang.github.io/2016/03/01/new-json-support-in-gosu.html for more information regarding JSON support in Gosu.